# Mongo query foreach within a normalized Euclidian distance

Tags: mongodb, distance

I am looking to rewrite a function I have at my application layer into a mongodb query.  The problem is that I want to return, for each record, a set of 10 records that have a nearest Euclidian distance along 2 normalized dimensions and one category.

My pseudocode now is...

```
for each record in collection:
   return records within 0.75 standard deviations of record's value for variable 1,
           within 0.5 sd of record's value for variable 2, 
           same value as record.variable3 # VAR3 is a categorical string 
   sort by (sqrt(((record.var1 - x.var1)/sd.var1)^2 + ((record.var2 - x.var2)/sd.var2)^2))
   limit 10
```

If I didn't have the conditions, or if I didn't have to normalize this upon query, or didn't have to apply it to each record in the collection, this would be a lot easier.  As you can guess, writing a local copy of my db along these parameters and the computing SDs, distances, and crunching the whole thing in python is really time-consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be possible in the query itself. You'd have to store transformed versions of the variables you want and do the rest in the application layer.